# Notepad++ C/C++ Preprocessor Highlight

Tags: notepad++

Does anyone know of a Notepad++ plugin that can change the background color inside a preprocessor `#if`, when it detects that the result is `false`?

Comment: That is a tough one!  
@user: how do you know it is false if it is a #ifdef VAR and VAR is defined at compilation level?

Comment: Right, I add to somehow tell Notepad++ where are all the headers/sources and let it search for defined preprocessor variables..

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I see is to use the great PythonScript plugin of Notepad++.

Once the plugin installed, you can write a python script.

- Create in your script a function `highlight_preprocessor` that does the following:

  1. Get the path of the file by using command `notepad.getCurrentFilename()`
  2. Parse all the header files included in your source file to retrieve values of potential pre-processor macros
  3. Remove any previous highlight
  4. Parse the text of your document and return the number of lines that should be high-lighted (by finding the `#if` blocks, assessing the boolean expression, and if "false" listing all the lines in the block between `#if` and `#endif`)
  5. For each line, call the function `editor.markerAdd(<line number>,10)`
  6. Set the colors of the high-light (e.g. dark gray) by calling the function `editor.markerSetBack(10, (200, 200,200) )` (where the last 3 numbers are the RGB values of the color)
- Call the function each time the file is saved by putting this line at the end of your script `notepad.callback(highlight_preprocessor, [NOTIFICATION.FILEBEFORESAVE])`

Takes some time and effort to make it work but at least it is possible.

Hope it can help some guy who would like to try.